# Docker nginx configuration always fall back to File not found

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to use Docker to develop a new Symfony app. However, I have some troubles when configuring nginx web server. I always fall back on 404 Not Found when I'm visiting localhost:8080. I should miss something in the global configuration.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx-webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:rw
      - ./.docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    container_name: php-fpm
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgresql-database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_database
      POSTGRES_USER: my_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libpq-dev

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install Symfony dependencies
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-interaction

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

nginx default.conf

```
# Nginx configuration

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /public/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
        # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

PS: the project looks like a "classic" project
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFumX.png)

Any help or improvements in my general Docker/nginx configuration would be appreciated !